# Swift string literal assignment to C variable

Tags: swift

In Swift, when calling C functions Swift strings are auto-coerced to CString when passed as parameters. However, I don't get the same behavior when filling out C structs or globals.

```
strlen(swiftString)                     //Works!
CGlobalStruct.stringPtr = swiftString   //Doesn't work!
```

First, Why do they behave different when they are both "const *char". Second, what is the cleanest way to fill out C Structs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Swift `String` can be passed as an argument to a function taking
a `UnsafePointer<Int8>` parameter. The compiler generates a temporary representation of the Swift string
as a NUL-terminated sequence of `char` and passes a pointer to 
that C String to the function. The representation and the pointer is *only valid during the function call.* That is what happens at

```
strlen(swiftString)
```

When assigning a global C string pointer then you have to take the
lifetime of this pointer into account. One possibility is

```
let swiftString = "Hello world"

swiftString.withCString {
    CGlobalStruct.stringPtr = $0

    // Pointer valid inside this closure ...
}
// Pointer not valid anymore ...
```

where a pointer to a C string representation is passed to the closure.
This pointer is (only) valid during the execution of the closure.

For longer-lived usage you could *allocate* a C string in memory,
but then you are responsible for freeing that memory eventually:

```
guard let cStringPtr = strdup(swiftString) else {
    fatalError("strdup failed")
}
CGlobalStruct.stringPtr = UnsafePointer(cStringPtr)

// ...

free(cStringPtr)
```

Comment: Very thoughtful response. The bridging of swift to c is quite good in most places, but if this is as good as it gets for assigning swift string literals to C structs... its kind of gross (not to mention obscure). Compare to the simplicity of bridging other types like CGlobalStruct.integer = 45

Comment: @TroyHarvey: Integers are "simple" types and have the same memory representation in C and Swift. A Swift String is a struct with opaque pointers to some backing store which can hold bytes (for pure ASCII strings) or UTF-16 code units, and is memory managed by Swift, whereas C strings are NUL-terminated sequences of chars. There is no simple bridging between them.