# Weird issues when passing an array of structs from Swift to C

Tags: swift

I'm passing an array of structs from Swift to a C function. The struct looks like this:

```
struct Struct {
    int a;
    float b;
    float c;
    const char* d;
    const char* e;
    const char* f;
    const char* g;
    int h[4];
};
```

Function signature of the C function:

```
void test(struct Struct* structs);
```

Weirdly, when I print `d` in the C function, it's often something different than what I set it to in the Swift code: usually an empty string or some garbage. When I set `d` to a very long string, it works correctly. The other strings are passed correctly too. Is that some struct alignment issue?

Comment: You need to show actual code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If this is an alignment issue, we probably need more details. What are `sizeof` and `alignof` of `int` and `float` in C? What are the actual pointer values? What compiler are you using, and for what machine?

Comment: How do you fill the struct in your Swift code? My guess would be that the `char *` members point to  C strings which were temporarily created from Swift strings, and are already deallocated or overwritten when the C function is called.

Comment: @DanielH: The struct layout in Swift can be different from C in general, but for structures *imported* from C, Swift preserves the layout (sizes, alignment, padding)

Comment: @MartinR I'm passing string literals to the struct's constructor, i.e. something like `Struct("test")`. But it seems that your guess was correct, the C strings are overwritten by whatever is written to the stack...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121442/swift-string-literal-assignment-to-c-variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinR suggested, when I pass the string to the struct's constructor, Swift creates a temporary C char array on the stack, copies the string's data into it and passes its pointer to the constructor. Immediately after that, the char array is no longer valid. Here's an example code demonstrating this:

```
let s = Struct(string: "string")
print(s.string) // Prints "string"
print("lol") // Overwrite the stack
print(s.string) // Prints "lol"
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40121697/243225 for possible solutions.